# Unable to get list of commands for a workflow state

Tags: workflow

Sitecore 8.2 Update 5

Kind of at a real loss here. Should be really simple code, just can't get the commands. In the code below workflow and workflow2 are not null and is the correct workflow.

In command, I am getting the commands for the current item's FieldIDs.WorkflowState. No commands are returned.

In command2, I am calling the state directly by ID. Still no commands are returned.

```
var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

var workflow = database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);
var command = workflow.GetCommands(item[FieldIDs.WorkflowState]); 

var workflow2 = database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow("{6AC12F8A-9374-41A3-B2D9-DBC7C9A0FB73}");  
var command2 = workflow2.GetCommands("{8B439291-76EE-46D2-ACEE-2BC67142D35F}");
```

Comment: If you try:    
   `var command = workflow.GetCommands(item[FieldIDs.WorkflowState]).FirstOrDefault();`
Do you get a result?

Comment: @JonFairchild No its an empty result

Comment: By the way, just to clarify, what version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: Sorry, updated question. Sitecore 8.2 Update 5

Comment: `IWorkflow workflow = item.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);

      if (workflow == null)
        return new WorkflowResult(false, "No workflow assigned to item");

      WorkflowCommand command = workflow.GetCommands(item[FieldIDs.WorkflowState])
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

      if (command == null)
        return new WorkflowResult(false, "Workflow command not found");`

What does that get you?

Comment: Wow, formatting is not working for me...

Comment: What is your context site?  this isn't clear from your code snippet or description. Not all sites have Workflow capabilities. Workflow needs to be enabled, on the corresponding `<site>` node. Assuming this is it - posting as answer and heading to bed ;-)

Comment: @MarkCassidy The site config has enableWorkflow="true". I am going to use a SiteContextSwitcher to see if there is a site issue.

Comment: Even as the publisher site, still no commands. Something is really wrong with this workflow. Maybe I should just rebuild it or decompile the workflow code.

Answer (score 4):

This one gets filed under the "doh" column. The user who is doing this action did not have access to the workflows. When I switched to `SecurityDisabler()`. The commands show up. This is a self service app where a user logs in with a limited Sitecore user to edit some content.

Thanks for the help Mark and Jon.

Answer (score 2):

#### Your context site needs to have Workflow enabled

For any Workflow functionality to work, you must be in the context of a site that has it enabled. By default, this would only be the `"shell"` site.

Your code and question does not mention what site context you are currently in, but I am assuming since you're requesting:

```
var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
```

that you are in a Site Context other than `"shell"` which would have this database by default. Asking for `"master"` by magic string is a nasty habit by the way, but let's leave that for now.

Either force your Site Context to `"shell"` using a `SiteContextSwitcher` or enable workflows on the context site you are running. Add `enableWorkflows="true"` to the `<site>` element for the site.